# Exception EL Expression Unbalanced:

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I am using JSF in my web application. I am passing parameters from my composite component to bean, but I am getting EL expression Unbalanced exception. Below is the code I am trying to use:

```
<h:panelGroup binding="#{datatableManagedBean.getDynamicDataTableGroup(#{cc.attrs.id})"/>
```

But I am getting below exception

```
javax.el.ELException: EL Expression Unbalanced: ... #{datatableManagedBean.getDynamicDataTableGroup(#{cc.attrs.id})
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.ELText.findVarLength(ELText.java:476)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.ELText.parse(ELText.java:396)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.ELText.parse(ELText.java:347)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.ELText.parse(ELText.java:338)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.ELText.isLiteral(ELText.java:321)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.TagAttributeImpl.<init>(TagAttributeImpl.java:127)
```

What can I try next?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Don't use EL expression inside another EL, you also forgot to close the first EL

Use this and notice the diff

`#{datatableManagedBean.getDynamicDataTableGroup(cc.attrs.id)}`

Comment: Daniel: Is there anyother way to achevie it,if using EL expression inside another EL is not the right approach.

Comment: I not sure what you want to achieve, but you should wrap your entire EL expression with the `#{myBean.myMethod(someVar)}` where `someVar` can be taken from inside `ui:repeat` / `h:datatable` / `ui:param` / `someOtherBean.someOtherValue` / etc...

Answer (score 5):

The error will be logged even when the '}' is missing. Something like:

```
<c:forEach items="#{customerRegistrationBean.accountWebData.selectedAccount" var="account">
...
```